# Android - Boot animation, static image before loading boot animation

Tags: android, operating-system, boot

I was working on changing boot animation on an android rooted device, I could successfully  change the boot animation but before loading animation there appears a stir image for few seconds. In my case, the device I use is MK 908, so the stir image is Google TV text on it. 
I wanted to know the location of that static image so that I can change that too.
Until now I could change boot animation by mounting to rw and copying bootanimation.zip to /system/media directory.

Can someone help me in figuring out the static image location before loading the animation ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi im quite sure i'm late but here :

I sure you looking for changing android boot logo usually file named logo.bin or logo.rle or splash.rle splash.bin also on newer versions i have seen extra partition with "LOGO" in name

anyway when you find the file you will be interested in rle2png converter 
but before flashing / adding file ensure the converter is converting properly by converting original file to png and back to rle  then hex compare results (on my lg android device first 4 bytes of file are size in big-endian) if the file is not same then do not use the new created file

anyway to find file easiest way i did:
adb shell ls -Rla>filelist.txt
(this will make a full file and folder list of your device)
i opened the resulting file and used command find with keywords mentioned above

in case you will need more assistance you can find me on xda @IGGYVIP

Hope that helps and gl